# How to apply negative regex on array in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation

Having this:

foo.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
@heds = map { /_h.+/ and s/^(.+)_.+/$1/ and "$_.hpp" } @ARGV;
@fls = map { !/_h.+/ and "$_.cpp" } @ARGV;

print "heds: @heds\nfls: @fls";
```

I want to separate headers from source files, and when I give input:

```
$./foo.pl a b c_hpp d_hpp
heds: e.hpp f.hpp
fls: e.cpp f.cpp a.cpp b.cpp
```

The headers are correctly separated, however the files are taken all. Why? I have applied the negative regex `!/_h.+/` in the mapping so the files with `*_h*` should  not be taken in account, but they are. Why so? and how to fix it?

Does not work even this:

```
@fls = map { if(!/_h.+/){ "$_.cpp" } } @ARGV;
```

still takes every files, despite the condition

Comment: Please correct you're output (e and f are not passed) and show how the output should look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map { }` for `@heds` includes a substitution on the `$1` argument and changes it. Just reorder the mapppings to avoid the effect on `@fls` and you get the desired result. Though, if you need to access `@ARGV` after these mappings it is not the original `@ARGV` anymore, like in your example code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
@fls = map { !/_h.+/ and "$_.cpp" } @ARGV;
@heds = map { /_h.+/ and s/^(.+)_.+/$1/ and "$_.hpp" } @ARGV;

print "heds: @heds\nfls: @fls\n";
```

Comment: but why map changes the original ARGV? it should *only* change the assignment array (fls) not the original one, from which it only *reads* the data

Comment: I'm not sure but the $1 is also the first argument in @ARGV

Comment: @milanHrabos Read [the documentation for `map`](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.32.0/functions/map.html). It tells you that modifying `$_` in the body of the map modifies the corresponding list element.

Comment: @Shawn ok, but if I want to make multiple substitution (and thus modifying the `$_`) then I have to have for each modification temporary array with copied content? I can I made multiple modification on array from the *original* array not changing its content then?

Comment: For not changing `$_` you could use `@heds = map { /_h.+/ and s/^(.+)_.+/$1/r . ".hpp" } @ARGV;`. The `/r` modifier makes s///r return the changed string without changing the original matched string (which is $_ here). Maybe there should be a my? And a grep to filter? Like `my @heds = map { s/^(.+)_.+/$1/r . ".hpp" } grep { /_h.+/ } @ARGV;`